# Writing a Lisp Function/Macro that will create functions

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to write a function/macro that will write a macro that will create a list structure. What's a good place to start. I'm looking to do something like `(mkList id name phone)` and having it result in a `(defun (id name phone) (list :id id :name name :phone phone))`, preferably with use of &rest. Any Ideas?

Comment: functions defined with `defun` need a name. in your `defun` form, the name is missing.

Comment: Camel case is mostly not used in Common Lisp.

Comment: FWIW, you probably don't need that macro.  The vast majority of problems can (and should) be solved without them.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you some hints:

```
CL-USER 39 > (defun foo (l)
               (cons 'list
                     (mapcan (lambda (e)
                               (list (intern (symbol-name e)
                                             (find-package "KEYWORD"))
                                     e))
                             l)))
FOO

CL-USER 40 > (foo '(a b c))
(LIST :A A :B B :C C)
```

Answer (score 0):

(defun mkcode (item) (eval (read-from-string item)))
Is what's working for me, let's me have a lot of flexibility

Comment: This answer seems entirely unrelated to your question.